# Writing change of co-ordinates in tensor notation

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

In page 45 of the book "Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces" , Pavel Grinield writes the equations governing coordinate transform from the system of $Z'$ to the system of $Z^{i}$

$$ Z^{i} = Z^{i} ( Z')$$

and, later writes,

$$ Z^{i} \equiv Z^{i} ( Z' (Z))$$

Now, what's the difference in meaning of these two identities? And what is the meaning denoted by the three line bar vs the equals sign?

So, before the book did this, it went over polar coordinates like $x(r, \theta) = r \cos \theta$ and $ y(r , \theta) = r \sin \theta$. And, then he went over if you plug $x$ and $y$ as function into $'r'$ as a function of $ 'x'$ and $ 'y'$

$$ r(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$$;

We get,

$$ r( x( r , \theta) , y(r , \theta) ) =r$$

r and $ \theta$ co-ordinates are denoted by $ Z'$

and,$ x,y$ co-ordinates are denoted by $Z$

as in,

$ Z^{1} = x$ and $Z^{2} = y$

and,

$ Z^{1'} = r $ and $ Z^{2' } =  \theta$

Comment: Please give us a bit of context here. What exactly are the "data types" (tensor shapes, perhaps) of $Z$ and $Z'$? What exactly does $Z^i(Z')$ mean?

Comment: So, before the book did this, it went over polar coordinates like $x(r, \theta) = r \cos \theta$ and $ y(r , \theta) = r \sin \theta$. And, then he went over if you plug this into the formula $$ r(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$$ as x and y then you get $$ r( x( r , \theta) , y(r , \theta) ) =r$$

r and $ \theta$ coordinates are denoted by $ Z'$

and,

Comment: Does the textbook have a symbolic index? Perhaps he says there what $\equiv$ means. Sometimes (in other texts) it is used to mean that the equation is a definition.

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't seen it noted explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pavel uses the symbols $Z^i=Z^i(Z')$
to denote dependence. That means he is considering the coordinates $Z^i$ as depending on the coordinate system $Z'$.

On the other hand, he uses $Z^i \equiv Z^i(Z'(Z))$
to mean that $Z$ and $Z'$ are inverse functions of each other.
You can see that from sections 4.6  and 4.7 (page 42 onwards).

Comment: In one of the equation, it is $ Z'(Z)$ and the other is just $ Z'$ , what's the difference?

Comment: @DDD4C4U I edited the post. Does that help?